# disable touch focus while loading

Tags: android, android-layout, touch-event

I have an android app that uses a `glSurfaceView` that takes a few sections to load up.

I have `onTouchEvent` overridden, and I'm trying to disable focus while it loads but `setFocusable(false)` isn't working.

The problem is if the user taps on the screen before everything loads, the app gets a null and it crashes.

Comment: You should post the applications LogCat output here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd pop up a progress dialog and use an AsyncTask to do the loading of the view.  Once the view is loaded you can kill the dialog.    Any heavy lifting should not be done on the UI thread anyway.